# MYSQL query between two timestamps

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have the following entry in my DB table

```
eventName(varchar 100) -> myEvent
date(timestamp) -> 2013-03-26 09:00:00
```

and I am trying to use the following query;

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventList 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1364256001) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1364342399)
```

i.e between 2013-03-26 00:00:01 and 2013-03-26 23:59:59

but it is giving me 0 results.

I have tried expanding the date range with no luck and there are definitely results within the range.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventList 
WHERE  `date` BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1364256001) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1364342399)
```

Or

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventList WHERE  `date` 
BETWEEN '2013-03-26 00:00:01' AND '2013-03-26 23:59:59'
```

Comment: if i create `$today_start = DateToTimestamp( date('Y-m-d h:i:s A', strtotime('today midnight')), $timezone );
$today_end = DateToTimestamp( date('Y-m-d h:i:s A', strtotime('-1 seconds ' ,strtotime('tomorrow midnight'))), $timezone );` and use this `BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME($today_start) AND FROM_UNIXTIME($today_end)` It is not returning what it should return thus i have to use directly the variables. This one does work one dates(in readable forms though like 2013-03-26 00:00:01) but not on timestamps, as in my case But not in general.

Comment: And why not supply directly the timestamps?

Answer (score 15):

Try this one. It works for me.

```
SELECT * FROM eventList
WHERE DATE(date) 
  BETWEEN 
    '2013-03-26' 
  AND 
    '2013-03-27'
```

Answer (score 8):

You just need to convert your dates to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. You can write your query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM eventList
WHERE
  date BETWEEN
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013/03/26')
      AND
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013/03/27 23:59:59');
```

When you don't specify the time, MySQL will assume `00:00:00` as the time for the given date.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `order_date_time`  BETWEEN 1534809600 AND 1536718364
```

Comment: Why would anyone write the timestamps value in a query? See the other answers on how to use formatted dates.

Comment: I don't know why this one works although if i have a timestamp and i would like to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mytimestamp)` OR `FROM_UNIXTIME(mytimestamp)` In my case these both are not working and using a php variable /direct timestamp works !

Answer (score 1):

Try this its worked for me

```
SELECT * from bookedroom
    WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-8-07 5:31')
        between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-8-07 5:30') and
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-8-09 5:30')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM eventList WHERE
date BETWEEN 
STR_TO_DATE('2013/03/26', '%Y/%m/%d')
AND
STR_TO_DATE('2013/03/27', '%y/%m/%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

@Amaynut Thanks

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventList 
WHERE date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-08-01') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017/08/01');
```

above mention, code works and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can even pass variables:

```
$timestamp_start = '2022-04-07 20:00:00.000'; // example
$timestamp_end   = '2022-04-21 20:00:01.000'; // example


AND table.date_created BETWEEN '$timestamp_start' AND '$timestamp_end'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code. Worked in my case. Hope this helps!

```
    select id,total_Hour,
    (coalesce(weekday_1,0)+coalesce(weekday_2,0)+coalesce(weekday_3,0)) as weekday_Listing_Hrs,
    (coalesce(weekend_1,0)+coalesce(weekend_2,0)+coalesce(weekend_3,0)) as weekend_Listing_Hrs
    from
    select *,
    listing_duration_Hour-(coalesce(weekday_1,0)+coalesce(weekday_2,0)+coalesce(weekday_3,0)+coalesce(weekend_1,0)+coalesce(weekend_2,0)) as weekend_3 
    from 
    (
    select * , 
    case when date(Start_Date) = date(End_Date) and weekday(Start_Date) in (0,1,2,3,4) 
         then timestampdiff(hour,Start_Date,End_Date)
         when date(Start_Date) != date(End_Date) and weekday(Start_Date) in (0,1,2,3,4) 
         then 24-timestampdiff(hour,date(Start_Date),Start_Date)
         end as weekday_1,  
    case when date(Start_Date) != date(End_Date) and weekday(End_Date) in (0,1,2,3,4) 
         then timestampdiff(hour,date(End_Date),End_Date)
         end as weekday_2,
    case when date(Start_Date) != date(End_Date) then    
    (5*(DATEDIFF(date(End_Date),adddate(date(Start_Date),+1)) DIV 7) + 
    MID('0123455501234445012333450122234501101234000123450',7 * WEEKDAY(adddate(date(Start_Date),+1))
    + WEEKDAY(date(End_Date)) + 1, 1))* 24 end as  weekday_3,
    case when date(Start_Date) = date(End_Date) and weekday(Start_Date) in (5,6) 
         then timestampdiff(hour,Start_Date,End_Date)
         when date(Start_Date) != date(End_Date) and weekday(Start_Date) in (5,6) 
         then 24-timestampdiff(hour,date(Start_Date),Start_Date)
         end as weekend_1,  
    case when date(Start_Date) != date(End_Date) and weekday(End_Date) in (5,6) 
         then timestampdiff(hour,date(End_Date),End_Date)
         end as weekend_2
    from 
    TABLE_1
    )
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. Please revise your answer and provide an explanation.

Comment: What is this pepperoni spaghetti doing?