# select MySQL record from date specific date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in fetching data from database, my date fromat is `1438697362` this value comes in result of this php default function `time();`

I am confused how can I fetch the data with this time and date format.

```
select * from table_name 
where  created_date 
BETWEEN '1438697362' AND '1440843077'
```

can anyone please help me in this matter.

Comment: can you please explain how can i use this function.

Comment: @kamranSheikh Checkout this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032335/mysql-query-between-two-timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table_name where created_date BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1438697362) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1440843077)
```

or

```
select * from table_name where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_date) BETWEEN 1438697362 AND 1440843077
```

Comment: thanks for help bro :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE created_date > 1438697362 AND created_date < 1440843077
```

This will select between the 2 date ranges

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:
[Convert Unix timestamp into human readable date using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267564/convert-unix-timestamp-into-human-readable-date-using-mysql)

Which says:

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(timestamp) 
FROM 
  your_table
```

answer by Parkyprg

or put another way:

```
SELECT other fields here, FROM_UNIXTIME(date_ordered)
FROM orders
WHERE ...
```

Comment: thanks to all for help