# query for time in mysql between hours

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how to get a list of rows that is between 17:30 till tomarrow 8:30.

```
--------------------------------------
| id | user_id | action |     time    |
--------------------------------------
| 1  |   25    | enter  | 1512459905  
| 2  |   19    |  exit  | 1512125105  
| 3  |   31    | enter  | 1514581905  |
--------------------------------------
```

mysql table have a time column with unix timestamp and i want get a list **every day** that between 17:30 till 8:30

Comment: $t1 = "17:30";
        $time1 = strtotime($t1);
         $t2 = "8:30";
        $time2 = strtotime($t2);
        $sql = "SELECT id,user_id,action from table WHERE time BETWEEN $time1 AND $time2";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL query between two timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032335/mysql-query-between-two-timestamps)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME('time 1'), FROM_UNIXTIME('time 2')) AS 'time_diff_in_sec' FROM 'your_table';
```

This can help:
[Mysql Get Time Diff](https://forum.ivorde.com/how-to-calculate-mysql-time-difference-between-unix-timestamp-column-and-now-format-t14241.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateStart=strtotime(date("Y-m-d 17:30:00"));
$dateEnd=strtotime(date("Y-m-d 20:30:00"));
```

This is how you can convert your date into unix timestamp in php.

Then in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE time BETWEEN '$dateStart' AND '$dateEnd'
```

If you don't want to execute your script manually every day you can set up a cronjob to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TIME() function to extract the time part of the datatime,
So you can do something like this:
select * FROM table t 
where TIME(f.time) between '17:30:00' AND '18:30:00'